# Sie liegt ihm ob

Tags: word-usage, separable-verb

Wie häufig wird das Verb *»obliegen«* als trennbares Verb verwendet?

Gestern musste der österreichische Bundespräsident Alexander van der Bellen als Exekutor des VfGH (Verfassungsgerichtshof) tätig werden, weil das Gericht Anfang März zur Erkenntnis kam, dass der Finanzminister Akten an einen Untersuchungsausschuss liefern muss, der Minister das aber bis zur Aktivierung des Bundespräsidenten nicht getan hat.<sup>1</sup> In einer öffentlichen Stellungnahme erklärte der Bundespräsident den rechtlichen Hintergrund dieses ungewöhnlichen Vorgangs und zitierte dabei den Artikel 146, Absatz 2 des österreichischen Bundesverfassungsgesetzes. Der erste Satz dieses Absatzes lautet:

> Die Exekution der übrigen Erkenntnisse des Verfassungsgerichtshofes liegt dem Bundespräsidenten ob.
> <sub>*Quelle: [B-VG Art. 146 Abs. 2](https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/NormDokument.wxe?Abfrage=Bundesnormen&Gesetzesnummer=10000138&Artikel=146&Paragraf=&Anlage=&Uebergangsrecht=)*</sub>

Gekürzt:

> Die Exekution **liegt** dem Präsidenten **ob.**

Nach meinem Sprachgefühl müsste es aber so heißen:

> Die Exekution **obliegt** dem Präsidenten.

Irre ich mich?

[Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/obliegen) und [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/obliegen) zufolge sind beide Formen richtig, und ich zweifle das auch nicht grundsätzlich an. Aber müsste nicht wenigstens die trennbare Form als *"veraltend"* oder *"selten"* gekennzeichnet werden? Wie häufig ist die Variante *»Sie liegt ihm ob«* im Vergleich zu *»Sie obliegt ihm«?*

---

Nebenfrage: Gibt es eigentlich auch noch andere Verben, die - ohne Änderung der Bedeutung - sowohl in einer trennbaren als auch in einer untrennbaren Form existieren?

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>*Der Finanzminister hat die Akten übrigens wenige Stunden nach der Veröffentlichung der Erklärung des Bundespräsidenten geliefert: 204 Aktenordner in 30 Umzugskartons. Die Lieferung war also schon vorbereitet und wäre vermutlich auch ohne diese Intervention bald erfolgt. Das konnten zu diesem Zeitpunkt aber weder das Gericht noch der Präsident wissen.*</sub>

Comment: Ein Blick ins Archiv zeigt, dass diese Textstelle schon in der Erstfassung auftaucht, und die stammt dem Jahre 1930 ent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mindestens bis zum Ende des 19. Jahrhunderts scheint *obliegen* ausschließlich als trennbares Verb gebraucht worden zu sein. So verzeichnen es die Brüder Grimm im [*Deutschen Wörterbuch*](https://woerterbuchnetz.de/?sigle=DWB&lemma=obliegen#0), wobei sie u.a. Fundstellen bei Goethe, Schiller und Wieland anführen.  [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/obliegen#d-1-1) kennt darüber hinaus Fundstellen bei Rathenau (1918) und Emil Strauß (1919), sodass diese Verwendung vermutlich auch noch in der Zwischenkriegszeit nicht ungewöhnlich war.  Dazu passt, dass die fragliche Formulierung in Art. 146 B-VG seit 1930 enthalten ist.  Nach der (zumindest heute geltenden) Faustformel, dass trennbare Silben betont sind, hat der Akzent damals vermutlich noch auf der Vorsilbe gelegen (*ób*liegen).

Im Laufe des 20. Jahrhunderts muss die Häufigkeit der getrennten Formen erheblich abgenommen und sich der Akzent infolgedessen auf ob*líe*gen verschoben haben. Das kann man auch im Vergleich durch [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=liegt%20ob%2Cobliegt&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=1&case_insensitive=true) ablesen: trotz der signifikanten Messfehler dadurch, dass bei der Suche nach *liegt ob* bei weitem nicht alle Stellungen im Satz erfasst werden (unterschätzt) und *obliegt* schon immer in Nebensätzen vorkam (überschätzt), sinkt zwischen 1945 und 1950 der Anteil von *liegt ob* auf quasi null, während *obliegt* ein Allzeithoch erreicht. Seit Mitte der 60er-Jahre nimmt die Verwendung dann insgesamt ab. In der heutigen Zeit ist der Gebrauch als trennbares Verb und die damit verbundene Betonung auf der ersten Silbe auch nach meiner Alltagserfahrung völlig unüblich. Die Formen können somit inzwischen zurecht als veraltet angesehen werden.

Zur Nebenfrage: Hierzu gibt es einen guten [Eintrag](http://mediawiki.ids-mannheim.de/VarGra/index.php/Trennbare_und_untrennbare_Verben) in der *Variantengrammatik* (VG; eine Kooperation schweizerischer und österreichischer Universitäten mit dem IDS in Mannheim). Laut dieser und DWDS sind fakultativ trennbar (ohne Anspruch auf Vollständigkeit):

> [aberkennen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/aberkennen), [anerbieten](https://www.dwds.de/wb/anerbieten), [anerkennen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/anerkennen), [auferlegen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/auferlegen), fachsimpeln*/**, [obliegen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/obliegen)**, [obsiegen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/obsiegen), [obwalten](https://www.dwds.de/wb/obwalten)**, [übersiedeln](https://www.dwds.de/wb/%C3%BCbersiedeln), [widerhallen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/widerhallen), widerschallen*, [widerspiegeln](https://www.dwds.de/wb/widerspiegeln)
>
> *alternative Formen nur in der VG (nicht im DWDS) enthalten
> **VG verweist auf *Ebner, Jakob (2009): Wörterbuch des österreichischen Deutsch*

Bei manchen dieser Verben hat sich der Gebrauch mit der Zeit verändert (diachrone Variation), bei anderen hängt er vom Gebiet ab (synchrone/areale Variation), wieder andere werden ohne räumliche Schwerpunkte nebeneinander gebraucht (synchrone/non-areale Variation).

**Diachrone Variation** Diese betrifft vor allem die Verben mit *ob-*: die getrennte Form *waltete ob* findet sich noch 1924 bei Mann im *Zauberberg*; *siegte ob* 1937 bei Ehm Welk (alle Fundstellen bei DWDS).  Genau andersherum verhält es sich mit *auferlegen*: Hier findet sich die zusammengesetzte Form (*war ein großer Richter …: er auferlegte Buße*) noch 1943 in Hesses *Glasperlenspiel* (und vielfach vor 1900 bei [*Google Books*](https://www.google.com/search?q=er+auferlegte&tbm=bks)), ist heute jedoch wohl ungebräuchlich. Diese gegensätzliche Entwicklung ist bemerkenswert, da *auf(er)legen* nichts anderes als die kausative Alternation von *obliegen* zu sein scheint. Allerdings gilt *auf-* mittlerweile als obligatorisch zu trennendes Präfix.

Das Interessante an *auferlegen, obliegen, obsiegen*, *obwalten* und auch *übersiedeln* ist ferner die laut [*Etymologischem Wörterbuch des Deutschen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/auf) enge Verwandtschaft der drei Präfixe, die  auf dieselbe indoeuropäische Wurzel zurückzuführen sind.  Der Verbbestandteil [*ob-*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/ob#wb-1) war ursprünglich eine Präposition wie [*über*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/ob#wb-1) (vgl. *Rothenburg [ob](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ob#2) der Tauber*; *ob dieser Worte*) und wurde laut DWB erst im Neuhochdeutschen zusammengerückt, was die (ursprüngliche) Trennbarkeit erklären würde; ebenso kann auch der Verbbestandteil *über-* trenn- oder untrennbar sein. Sofern diese Verben als trennbar behandelt werden, ist jedoch eine Betonung auf dem Präfix zu erwarten.

**Areale synchrone Variation** Dazu gehören *anerkennen*, *übersiedeln* und *widerspiegeln*. In Deutschland überwiegt der trennbare Gebrauch, während die Verben in der Schweiz (und Süd(west)deutschland) meist ungetrennt erscheinen. In Österreich wird *widerspiegeln* laut VG fast immer getrennt, *übersiedeln* aber nicht, und *anerkennen* regional unterschiedlich gehandhabt.

**Non-areale synchrone Variation** Dazu zählt die VG *aberkennen, anerbieten, auferlegen, widerhallen* und *widerschallen*.  Aufgrund des insgesamt seltenen Gebrauchs seien hier keine genauen Häufigkeiten zu ermitteln.

Comment: Großartige Antwort! Vielen Dank!

Comment: Die Präposition *»ob«* findet sich nicht nur in vielen Ortsnamen wieder sondern wird auch heute noch aktiv verwendet, bedeutet aber dasselbe wie *»wegen«* und verlangt den Genitiv: Februar '21: [Die FPÖ ist fassungslos **ob** des Abwahlantrags](https://www.tt.com/artikel/17831684/gruener-abwahlantrag-sorgt-fuer-blaue-empoerung-in-innsbruck) März '21: [Die Gastgärten waren **ob** des nasskalten Wetters noch kein Thema](https://www.falstaff.at/nd/gastro-oeffnung-in-vorarlberg/) April '21: [Der Handel ist **ob** des andauernden Lockdowns zunehmend verzweifelt](https://noe.orf.at/stories/3100004/)

Comment: Das stimmt und ist bemerkenswert, da die Präp. bereits in der 2. Aufl des EtymWb. von 1993 als [*heute ungebräuchlich* und *altertümlich*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/etymwb/ob) bezeichnet wird! Hergeleitet wird diese Bedeutung im DWB übrigens vom ahd. *opa deru sahhu*, wörtlich also 'über dieser Sache' (vgl. lat. *quam ob rem*). Ebenso erstaunlich, dass wie bei *trotz* der Genitiv den ursprünglichen Dativ verdrängt hat. Die Brüder Grimm dazu: "*dieser genetiv ist wol durch ausgelassenes wegen zu erklären:* da hat es *(das pferd)* ob solches wegen über einen berg herab gestürzt."

Comment: Ein anderes, und wie ich finde aussagekräftigeres, Ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=liegt+ihm+ob%2Cobliegt+ihm&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=1&case_insensitive=true

Answer (score 9):

Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/obliegen) kennzeichnet die getrennte Form als *veraltend* oder *veraltet*. Das entspricht auch meinem Sprachgefühl.

Auszug aus obigem Link:

> **Rechtschreibung INFO**
> Worttrennung: ob|lie|gen
> Beispiele: es obliegt, oblag mir, es ist mir oblegen; zu obliegen, **veraltend auch es liegt, lag mir ob**; es hat mir obgelegen; obzuliegen

Comment: Ich habe mal den relevanten Auszug hier eingefügt... kann ja immer mal sein, dass der Link sich ändert, und dann steht da Deine Antwort ohne konkreten Beleg...